# Is there a way to see more than 1,000 warnings?

Tags: stylecop

I'm seeing that StyleCop cancelled after 1,000 warnings.
Is there a way to see more than 1,000 warnings?

------ StyleCop 4.7 (build 4.7.59.0) started ------

Pass 1:   testProject - \App.xaml.cs

Pass 1:   testProject - \Modules\Administration\Models\DocumentClass.cs

Pass 1:   testProject - \Modules\Administration\Models\DocumentType.cs

Pass 1:   testProject - \Modules\Administration\Models\LetterGroup.cs

Pass 1:   testProject - \Modules\Administration\Models\LetterType.cs

------ StyleCop cancelled ------

Comment: Why? Fix the 1000 you can already see, and then run again to see more. Rinse and repeat until there are no more.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree, but I am working in a code base with millions of lines of code. I am indeed fixing these as I go along, but there are certain StyleCop errors that take priority and I want to address those first.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer You can choose which StyleCop checks are performed: [Managing StyleCop Project Settings](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Managing%20StyleCop%20Project%20Settings).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Please add this as an answer. This worked out for me.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer Feel free to write it up as an answer: it'll be fresh in your mind whereas I haven't done StyleCop rule selection for rather a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to limit the number of StyleCop checks to only the on the ones I care about. If your solution contains multiple projects, then you would have to go to each project, right-click on the project and limit the search criteria for StyleCop.

More details on [Managing StyleCop Project Settings](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Managing%20StyleCop%20Project%20Settings).